# Eclipse IDE and/or NetBeans not opening because of Java Error Code: 1603

Tags: java, qa-developer, eclipse

I'm trying to setup Eclipse on my local drive for Selenium 2.0/WebDriver but getting the following error when opening the application:

```
 Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0v20140925-0400\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v201
40603-1326\eclipse_1603.dll
-startup
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2e60_5c
product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

...which I thought looked like a Java issue - so I tried installing the latest version and got this half way through:

```
! Java update did not complete
Error code: 1603
```

I've tried:

- Uninstalling & re-installing Eclipse IDE
- Deleting & re-installing Eclipse IDE files
- Updating Java JDK

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Dan

**Edit:** This is also preventing NetBeans from installing so it's definitely a Java issue. Just to clarify, I've tried NetBeans as well as Eclipse to find the root cause, I'm not trying to get them both working simultaneously. Getting this midway through the NetBeans installation:

```
Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException:
null
```

Comment: Why you want both? eclipse and netbeans? Eclipse is enough for selenium2 programs.

Comment: Hey, I made an edit but the title's probably not clear now. I tried Eclipse first but was getting an error, so tried Netbeans as well to see if I could work around it but, alas, it's definitely a Java issue.

Comment: Do you using latest JDK and have you set proper classpath?

Comment: Okay, I got into work and opened my laptop... "Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 31 has successfully installed", which is odd because I don't remember setting it off last night! Have tried running Eclipse again and am getting 'exit code = 2' now, which sounds like progress. I found an answer on StackOverflow which said to delete the java path in Environment Variables, but that didn't work. Another suggested deleting java.exe and javaw.exe, but that didn't work either... the investigation continues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution wasn't to delete the java path or to delete the java.exe and javaq.exe files - it was pretty much the opposite!

After uninstalling and re-installing JDK 8 (which took me to Update 40), I added the `PATH` variable and directory to environment variables, which was the same as before, so I guess there was a version incompatibility which update 40 resolved

So the steps were:

- Search for 'Environment Variables' in your Start Menu's search function and click on 'Edit environment variables for your account'
- Delete the existing `PATH` variable under the System Variables header
- Download or update Java to the latest version and install
- If Eclipse or NetBeans still won't open, find the directory of the javapath folder
- Open the Environment Variables panel again
- Create a new System Variable called `PATH` and set the Value to wherever your javapath folder is.

Anywho, hope this helps someone in future. It was a nightmare for me but got there in the end!

[image: Environment Variables panel]

Comment: Happy to hear that your issue resolved..:)